# PtrToStrAnsi faster alternative?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am looking for a function that could quickly convert an unmanaged string to a managed one. I was looking at `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`, but it's really slow.

I see in the .NET framework source code the following definition:

```
public static String PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr ptr)
{
    if (Win32Native.NULL == ptr) {
        return null; 
    }
    else if (IsWin32Atom(ptr)) { 
        return null; 
    }
    else { 
        int nb = Win32Native.lstrlenA(ptr);
        if( nb == 0) {
            return string.Empty;
        } 
        else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(nb); 
            Win32Native.CopyMemoryAnsi(sb, ptr, new IntPtr(1+nb)); 
            return sb.ToString();
        } 
    }
}
```

In order to improve performance of my application I created the following method that uses the Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr, int) method that is much faster.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "lstrlenA")]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
internal static extern int lstrlenA(IntPtr ptr); 

static public string PtrToString( IntPtr p )
{
   if (p == IntPtr.Zero)
      return null;
   int len = lstrlenA(p);
   if (len == 0)
      return string.Empty;
   return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p, len);
}
```

This alternative seems much faster. Is there a reason why Microsoft did not code the PtrToStringAnsi function in the first place? I am probably missing something important...

Comment: It's not the same function. The second method calls the version PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr,int) not PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr)

Comment: Can you show the benchmark program

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5161459

Comment: So the difference is in the call to `IsWin32Atom`? Perhaps that's important?

Comment: @JimMischel: no that call is really really fast. There is something behind that `StringBuilder` that I don't understand. Why would you need a StringBuilder there??

Comment: I don't know what `PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr, int32)` does, but I suspect it uses a `StringBuilder`, as well. You have to allocate memory for the copy *somehow*, and `StringBuilder` is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the call to `IsWin32Atom`. Your version omits that. When you put it back you will find that your version is then comparable to the version in `Marshal`. Even when you remove the call to  `IsWin32Atom` the performance gain is negligible.

My version of your test program looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "lstrlenA")]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        internal static extern int lstrlenA(IntPtr ptr);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern System.IntPtr GetCommandLine();

        private static readonly IntPtr HIWORDMASK = unchecked(new IntPtr((long)0xffffffffffff0000L));

        private static bool IsWin32Atom(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            long num = (long)ptr;
            return 0 == (num & (long)HIWORDMASK);
        }

        public static string PtrToString(IntPtr p)
        {
            if (p == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;
            if (IsWin32Atom(p))
                return null;
            int len = lstrlenA(p);
            if (len == 0)
                return String.Empty;
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p, len);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Console.WriteLine(\"Marshal class: result={0} time={1}ms\", s, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);");

            string s = "";
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (double i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(p);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Marshal class: result={0} time={1}ms", s, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();
            for (double i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
            {
                s = Program.PtrToString(p);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("My implementation: result={0} time={1}ms", s, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The runtime varies a fair bit from run to run. But here's a typical output:

```
Marshal class: result=Console.WriteLine("Marshal class: result={0} time={1}ms", 
  s, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); time=1914ms
My implementation: result=Console.WriteLine("Marshal class: result={0} time={1}ms", 
  s, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); time=2065ms
```

But sometimes it comes out the other way around. In short, nothing to choose between the two.

When you remove the call to `IsWin32Atom`, then your version wins more often than not. But not by much. There's typically around a 5% difference in speed. I don't know why you think that `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` is "very slow".

I very much expect that the two parameter version of `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` is essentially the `else` clause of your code.

*Note*: My test environment was Win7 x64, VS2012, AnyCPU, Release.

Comment: +1 Thanks for doing the research on this one. I copied your code and verify your results. .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2012, Release mode, no debugger attached.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Strange, I run the exact same code, and I get 56s for version 1 and 20s for version 2

Comment: 56s? My code is done in 2s. Your machine won't be 30 times slower than mine.

Comment: I meant ms. I run in release mode

Comment: Well that can't be right either. 2000ms for me, 56 for you. My machine is not that bad.

Comment: My timings are between 1000 and 1100 ms. Win7, x64, AnyCPU, Release.